# How do I write a CoreGraphics CGImageRef from custom data stream?

Tags: c++, objective-c, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

What i'm hoping to end with is a Core Graphics CGImageRef that is drawn to the screen in an overridden -(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect method. Here's what i've got so far.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    const CGFloat _x = CGRectGetMinX(rect);
    const CGFloat _y = CGRectGetMinY(rect);
    const CGFloat _w = CGRectGetWidth(rect);
    const CGFloat _h = CGRectGetHeight(rect);

    const CGFloat scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];

    const int pixelsWide = (_w * scale);
    const int pixelsHigh = (_h * scale);

    const size_t colorValues = 4;
    const int rawMemorySize = (pixelsWide * pixelsHigh * colorValues);

    // raw pixel data memory
    UInt8 pixelData[rawMemorySize];

    // fill the raw pixel buffer with arbitrary gray color for test

    for(size_t ui = 0; ui < rawMemorySize; ui++)
    {
        pixelData[ui] = 255; // black
    }

    CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CFDataRef rgbData = CFDataCreate(NULL, pixelData, rawMemorySize);
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(rgbData);

    CGImageRef rgbImageRef = CGImageCreate(pixelsWide, pixelsHigh, 8, (colorValues * colorValues), (pixelsWide * colorValues), colorspace, kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault, provider, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

    CFRelease(rgbData);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);

    //Draw the bitmapped image
    CGContextDrawImage(currentContext, CGRectMake(_x, _y, pixelsWide, 64), rgbImageRef);
    CGImageRelease(rgbImageRef);
}
```

I'm thrown an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error within the for loop.

I think i'm close, but i'm not exactly sure. Any ideas what might be the culprit? Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple more things to be aware of.

The `rect` argument to drawRect is only the dirty rectangle, which may be smaller than `self.bounds`.  Use `self.bounds` unless your code is optimized to only draw the dirty rectangle.

Allocating the `pixelData` array on the stack is a bad idea, and may be the cause of the error. It all depends on how big the view is.  I suspect that AaronGolden was using a smaller view than you were, and hence didn't have any problems.  It's safer to `calloc` the array, and free it at the end after you're done using it.  Note that `calloc` will clear the array to transparent black.

Here's some sample code that I've used to do this sort of thing in the past. Even though the pixel array is created with a `calloc`, you can still access it like a standard array (e.g. `pixels[100] = 0xff0000ff;` is perfectly valid).  However, for performance reasons, I typically use a pointers to access individual pixels.

```
const CGFloat scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
int width  = self.bounds.size.width  * scale;
int height = self.bounds.size.height * scale;

uint32_t *pixels = calloc( width * height, sizeof(uint32_t) );
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate( pixels, width, height, 8, width * sizeof(uint32_t), colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast );

uint8_t *bufptr = (uint8_t *)pixels;
for ( int y = 0; y < height; y++)
{
    for ( int x = 0; x < width; x++ )
    {
        bufptr[0] = redValue;
        bufptr[1] = greenValue;
        bufptr[2] = blueValue;
        bufptr[3] = alphaValue;

        bufptr += 4;
    }
}

CGImageRef newCGImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage( context );
CGContextRelease( context );
CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );
free( pixels );
```

Comment: Great point about the stack allocation.  I tried it again in the iPad-retina simulator and sure enough hit the bad access in the for loop as @achi described.

Comment: what might calloc look like in code? the benefit of a sized array was that I could access the data at an index.With calloc will I have to bit shift manually?

Comment: @achi I added some code to my answer.  I've not used the provider mechanism before, so I'm just showing you how I've done something similar in the past.  The memory returned by calloc can be treated just as if it was an array.  Typically, I declare the pointer as `uint32_t` so that each entry in the array is a full pixel, including alpha.

Comment: thanks for the help! might you be able to offer a good resource for uint32_t mathematics? I haven't worked with that variable type much and i'm not quite sure yet how I might be able to manipulate it easily

Comment: @achi -- `uint32_t` is a 32-bit unsigned number.  I started programming a long long time ago, so the only resource I had was the book titled *The C Programming Language* by Kernighan and Ritchie.  If you're uncomfortable with 32-bit math, it's probably best to avoid it, since it gets all tangled up in the issue of endianess.  I've modified the answer to use `uint8_t` to access the pixels.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of suggestions.  I tried your code and didn't hit a bad access in the for loop, like you describe, but:

You don't need a for loop to set everything to 255 like that.  You can use `memset`:

```
memset(pixelData, 255, sizeof(pixelData));
```

And in your call to CGImageCreate, the argument immediately after your literal 8 is wrong.  That's supposed to be the number of bits per pixel, which is `8 * colorValues` not `colorValues * colorValues`.  So create your image like:

```
CGImageRef rgbImageRef = CGImageCreate(pixelsWide, pixelsHigh, 8, 8 * colorValues, pixelsWide * colorValues, colorspace, kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault, provider, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
```

Finally, I noticed that you put a comment saying the 255's corresponded to black, but that's not right.  If you make all your pixel data bytes 255 your image should be full *white*.  You draw your image with a height of 64 points in your CGContextDrawImage call, and indeed I see a *white* bar 64 points tall when I run your code with these corrections.

Comment: (of course 255 is white, dumb mistake!) But, I intend to eventually write a custom gradient - for now, though, i'm setting every value to 255 as a placeholder. So, memset won't work for me :/

Comment: @achi: Are you *sure* you're hitting the EXC_BAD_ACCESS in your for loop?  I copied your code exactly into a new project and didn't see any issues until the `CGImageCreate`.